# Load content in a div of a php page using ajax when some data is inserted in another php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have 2 php pages; first is chat view page which is my global display page & the other page is one where i insert my data.
How do i load a that data in this page's div when i insert some text in another php file from my iPad application.
My problem is i need to refresh this page manually to load all the contents which isnt the right thing to do in a chat application.
As my chat view page has no event to load the div how do i do this.
Has some ajax or jquery logic behind this as far as i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply ajax won't be enough to do the thing what you want. This is actually opposite of `ajax` and called as [comet programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) where the server should make some events to notify the client which has new data. Therefore the client should have some sort of interaction with the server to accomplish this. Few technology terms I can remember are

1. [long polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling) -- similar to normal polling but at lower frequency
2. [server side events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) -- [better explanation](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/)
3. [web sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) -- [explained](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/) , [popular lib](http://socket.io/)

*hope I made it clear some sort*

Comment: Awesome ! Will go ahead & implement this ;) Exactly what i was looking for !

Answer (score 1):

**USE**

JQUERY [.load](https://api.jquery.com/load/)

> Description: Load data from the server and place the returned HTML
>   into the matched element.

and [$.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/%E2%80%8E)

Comment: This is what i wanted & knew, bt how do i trigger the onclick event.. i have no button.. Thats my issue.. i dont hav any event to load the div.. it needs to be done automatically..

Comment: Either you need to check if new recodes ecits or need to use websockets

Comment: use setTimeOut function